# Problem with apt-get update and dpkg/status

Tags: updates, dpkg

First i got some problems with /var/lib/dpkg/status. I found a solution to remove this file and run apt-get update. Removing this file worked well but after running update i always got this errormessagen (sorry, german system, german errormessage):

```
Es wurden 200 kB in 4 s geholt (43,5 kB/s).
W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  Bitte verwenden Sie apt-cdrom, um APT diese CD-ROM bekannt zu machen. apt-get update kann nicht dazu verwendet werden, neue CD-ROMs hinzuzufügen.

W: Fehlschlag beim Holen von cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Bitte verwenden Sie apt-cdrom, um APT diese CD-ROM bekannt zu machen. apt-get update kann nicht dazu verwendet werden, neue CD-ROMs hinzuzufügen.

E: Einige Indexdateien konnten nicht heruntergeladen werden. Sie wurden ignoriert oder alte an ihrer Stelle benutzt.
```

how can i fix the problem with list file and executing update?

Answer (score 2):

Open Update Manager and click on the "Settings" button to open Software Sources. Click on the Ubuntu tab and un-check the "Cdrom with Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail" source.

Öffnen Sie Update-Manager und klicken Sie an die „Einstellungen“ knöpfen, um Software-Quellen zu öffnen an. Klicken Sie an den Ubuntu Tabulator und die UNOkontrolle der „CD-ROM mit Ubuntu 13,04 Quelle Raring Ringtail“.

Comment: Can not open update manager (don´t know why). there is a way to do by terminal?

Comment: Yes (if you cannot access it through the method in the other answer). Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` using `sudo` privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You can open, System Setting.

[image]

And ENTER Softwares and Update. 
From there just UN-check "Cdrom with Ubuntu 13.04 'Raring Ringtail'". My problem was solved by this step. Hope it will help you too.